# Net Core 3.1 + Swagger + nginx Unable to render this definition

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, swagger, swagger-ui

I am having issues to get Swagger UI working properly.
I am running a microservice architecture on kubernetes, everything gets into through an NGinX ingress that looks like this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  namespace: develop
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$2"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "*"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origins: "*"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: "*"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /api/users(/|$)(.*)
          backend:
            serviceName: dds-users-api-clusterip
            servicePort: 80
        - path: /api/search(/|$)(.*)
          backend:
            serviceName: dds-search-api-clusterip
            servicePort: 80
```

On the other hand, I have a couple of asp.net core 3.1 APIs with a couple of endpoints. I am using swagger and swagger UI. Everything works fine locally, either on docker or Visual Studio, however Swagger UI doesn't work on kubernetes. The API works just fine, the swagger.json also works fine. Only Swagger UI fails with this error:

[image]

This is the swagger.json:

```
// http://{server}/api/users/swagger/v1/swagger.json

{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "Users API",
    "description": "Users API",
    "version": "v1"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/user/changepassword": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "User"
        ],
        "requestBody": {
          "content": {
            "application/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ChangePasswordRequest"
              }
            },
            "text/json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ChangePasswordRequest"
              }
            },
            "application/*+json": {
              "schema": {
                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ChangePasswordRequest"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "responses": {
          "204": {
            "description": "Success"
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "Bad Request",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ProblemDetails"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "Not Found",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ProblemDetails"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "ChangePasswordRequest": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "currentPassword": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
          },
          "newPassword": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      },
      "ProblemDetails": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
          },
          "status": {
            "type": "integer",
            "format": "int32",
            "nullable": true
          },
          "detail": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
          },
          "instance": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": {
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore and Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger 5.4.1. The configuration is pretty straightforward, nothing too special:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version = "v1",
        Title = "Users HTTP API",
        Description = "Swagger Users API",
    });
});

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
});
```

[image]

As you can see from the debug console, the UI is requesting the swagger.json document to the wrong URL, it is not including /api/users prefix

So the following routes work:

- http://{server}/api/users/user/changePassword
- http://{server}/api/users/swagger/v1/swagger.json

I am really stuck on this point, can't move forward.
I really appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Your *swagger.json* file is returned with `Content-Type: text/html`. Can you tweak your server configs so that the *swagger.json* file is returned with `Content-Type: application/json` and see if if helps?

Answer (score 0):

The request path for get swagger.json is `/swagger/v1/swagger.json`

But you missed to add http rule in you `ingress object` to redirect to your backend for `/swagger` path